# RichEditBox and ITextCharacterFormat.ProtectedText

Tags: c#, xaml, text, formatting

I have a RichEditBox and a Button. When the button is clicked, the event handler is supposed to set the current selection in the RichEditBox as **[protected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.itextcharacterformat.protectedtext.aspx)**.

However, once the handler is executed, the selected text doesn't seem to be protected since i can change its content and completely delete it (deleting isn't really an issue, I just would like to prevent the user from changing the text value).

What am I missing out ?

Here is the code used in the event handler. (`MyRichEditBox` is the `x:Name` set in the XAML of the RichEditBox).

```
private void ProtectTextButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ITextSelection selectedText = MyRichEditBox.Document.Selection;
    if (selectedText != null)
    {
        ITextCharacterFormat formatting = selectedText.CharacterFormat;

        formatting.ProtectedText = FormatEffect.On;
        selectedText.CharacterFormat = formatting;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug... I created [a new post about this](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/32695468-fix-richeditbox-protectedtext-doing-nothing) in Windows Developer Feedback site if you want to give it a vote!